# Base liner for stucco wall

Tags: exterior, masonry, baseboard, stucco

I need ideas how to cover this currently really ugly joint between my stucco wall (currently applying stucco, can see new layer) and the immediate surrounding currently done with paver stones and sand, which also needs to be redone. I was thinking something like exterior tiles, if there is such a thing, and just apply a sequence around the base of the stucco.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I will do since the shape is irregular which would mean lots of tiles cutting

Remove a quarter to half an inch of the dirt

Get a small bag of self leveling concrete

Mask with the tape the bricks to prevent concrete on them

Apply the self leveling concrete and fill the gaps